# Sum quantities based on two columns and multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

In excel, I have three columns.  Column A contains receipt numbers, Column B contains item numbers, and Column C contains the quantity of each item. Example ("Receipt#" is in cell A1):

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ Receipt  ║ Item# ║ Quantity ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ x        ║ a     ║       14 ║
║ x        ║ a     ║       26 ║
║ x        ║ b     ║       30 ║
║ x        ║ c     ║       68 ║
║ y        ║ a     ║       79 ║
║ y        ║ c     ║        3 ║
║ y        ║ c     ║       24 ║
║ z        ║ b     ║       91 ║
║ z        ║ a     ║        5 ║
║ z        ║ a     ║        1 ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

I would like to sum the quantities belonging to the same Receipt# AND Item# in Column D.

I've tried `SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A3=A2,B:B,B3=B2)` which returns 0.
I've tried `IF(A3=A2,(IF(B3=B4,SUM(C5,C4),"")),"")` which sums but not like I want, I only want one total per Item# AND Receipt#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be using wrong criterias. See formula below.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A1,B:B,B1)
```

Comment: This works, thank you!  The example I used was a truncated table, my actual data set contains over 350 unique Receipt #'s so I was trying to avoid direct references. I can then use sort & filter to remove duplicate entries from the summing results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=E1),--(B:B=E2),C:C)
```

[image]